# Asymptotic function suggestion please

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

Can someone suggest a function to fit these requirements:

- $f(x) \to x$ as $x \to -\infty$
- $f(x) \to 1$ from below as $x \to \infty$
- Well-behaved at $x=0$.
- Doesn't overshoot
- Reasonably easy to control how "sharp" the knee is.
- $0 < \frac{df}{dx} < 1$ for all $x$.

I'm basically looking for a smooth transition from $f(x) = x$ up to nearly 1 to $f(x) = 1$ from just over 1 onwards, with a parameter to control how big "nearly" and "just over" are.

The closest I've come up with is $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + x/a^x} + \frac{1}{1 - x/a^{-x}}$ where $a$ is about $0.7$.  But this has a noticeable overshoot and grows too fast over $0 < x < 1$.

EDIT: Should have noted that "Well-behaved at $x = 0$" includes being *numerically* well-behaved around that point, not just mathematically well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off @Saturday's example, here's one that should also meet the $f(x)\to x$ as $x\to -\infty$ condition:
$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{1-e^{x-1}}+1$$

[image]

Comment: This gives the form I'm after, but still has numerical problems around `x = 1`.

Comment: @Tom I didn't see any condition on your list. Could you elaborate what additional behavior you require at x=1?

Comment: you're right, I should have said "well-behaved for all x" rather than "at x=0".  The problem is that, at x=1, the denominator goes to 0.  It's mathematically well-behaved, in that the numerator behaviour around this point keeps the exact value small; the problem is that, when the value of x is very close to 1, limited numerical precision (ie when calculating using double-precision floating-point numbers) makes the result a bit unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

How about

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^x}+1$$

[image: enter image description hercccccce]

Comment: The problem here is that `f(x) -> x+1` as x becomes large and negative, where the requirement stated `f(x) -> x`.  Because of this, it's quite hard to control the sharpness of the knee - making the denominator `1 - exp(a*x)` controls the shape well enough, but the line only passes through `0, 0` if `a = 1`.